# Spring security: loadUserByUsername() not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security(3.1.4), spring security doesn't invokes the loadUserByUsername() method. I have a custom login page which authenticates a user using a custom UserDetailsService bean which is not invoking the loadUserByUsername() so, getting following exception(nullPointerException)

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myWebapp] in   context with path         [/urbanbinge-web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception       is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at  `enter code here`in.urbanbinge.rest.LoginController.authenticate(LoginController.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at in.urbanbinge.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter.doFilter(PreRenderSEOFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here, is configuration files

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Urban Binge</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/myWebapp-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/security-context-config.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/applicationcontext-social.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myWebapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myWebapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>urbanBingeWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>prerender</filter-name>
    <filter-class>in.urbanbinge.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter</filter-class></filter>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

security-context-config.xml

```
 <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" /> 

<http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="unauthorisedEntryPoint"/>
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/#!/login"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/users/userinfo/*" access="hasAnyRole('A','O','E','M')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/users/del" access="hasAnyRole('A','O','E','M')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secured/users/add" access="permitAll"/>


 <!-- Other configurations -- >



 <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder  hash="sha-256" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

note : in above config file hasAnyRole() parameters A,O,M,E are roles

**CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl java class**

```
 @Service("customUserDetailsService")
 public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserDetails userDetails = null;
    try {
        LOGGER.debug("loadUserByUsername : username : "+username);
   // I put a break point in below statement using intellij idea but call didn't came here      
     in.urbanbinge.orm.entities.User user = userRepository.findByEmailId(username);
        userDetails = new User(user.getEmailId(),user.getPassword(),(user.getIsActive() == 0 ? false : true), true, true, true, getAuthorities(user.getRole()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error : "+e.getMessage());
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error in retrieving user");
    }
    LOGGER.debug("UserDetails Found : "+userDetails);
    return userDetails;
}

 public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(final String role) {

        // Create a list of grants for this user
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);

        // Assigning role to the user
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));

        LOGGER.debug("authList : "+authList);

        // Return list of granted authorities
        return authList;
  }
```

Comment: Add the controller, also why do you have a controller? Spring Security should be in charge. Your configuration is also flawed as you are loading your beans defined in `myWebapp-servlet.xml` twice.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities ( although very basic ) is that the authentication is failing. Unless the username and password dont clear the authentication the loadUserByUsername() doesnt get called.
Kindly let me know if this solution helped you.

Comment: hmm can you do a final check by running a query in the database, just to make sure the password is correct

Comment: i did that as well i got result .. no issue with password .. im sure that username and password are correct

Comment: Add this line your security xml
 <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="yourpackagename.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>

Comment: Kindly let me know if the suggested solution helped you

Comment: add this 
`<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider ref="openIdAuthProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>
  <bean id="openIdAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="registeringUserService"/>
  </bean>
<bean id="registeringUserService" class="yourpackagename.CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>`

Comment: Kindly let me know if the proposed solution helped you or if you had some problem with the proposed steps. If it has fulfilled the problem solution then kindly accept the solution.